# Hide scrollbar for body in HTML5

Tags: css, html

In html5, the attribute was removed `scroll="no"` for element body.

What is the alternative?

Comment: Do you want to hide the scrollbar or prevent scrolling altogether?

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
<body style="overflow: hidden">
```